# How can I capture / log a fatal error in Swift?

Tags: swift

For example, `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. Regardless of the cause, can this data be captured? Is this `stderr` or something else?

**Edit:** I found a reference at http://swiftdoc.org/func/fatalError/ that says the function (which I'm assuming is indeed what Swift is internally calling) "Unconditionally print a message and stop execution.". So perhaps there's nothing left to do but get ahold of the remote crash report via TestFlight crash reports or actually having the device handy.

I'm able to log all uncaught exceptions via `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` in `main.swift`, and we have good logging going on in other parts of our app wherever bad (but possible) errors can occur. I was hoping to also log these fatal errors so that our logs show a more complete picture of crashes occuring on remote testing devices.

Comment: What data are you looking to capture exactly?

Comment: Well, It would be nice to simply capture the fatal error string and use it for additional debugging. I'm using Logentries to log errors, uncaught exceptions, etc., in an app while we're developing it across several team members. Fatal errors should def be logged if at all possible, but I'm scratching my head as to how.

Answer (score 1):

Certain errors will go to `stderr`.  Here is a simple example:

```
$ cat tryit 
#! /usr/bin/env swift

println ("foo")
precondition (false, "bar")
$ ./tryit 2> /tmp/error 1> /tmp/noterror
Illegal instruction: 4
$ cat /tmp/noterror 
$ cat /tmp/error
precondition failed: bar: file ./tryit, line 4
0  swift                    0x000000010f7faa18 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 40
1  swift                    0x000000010f7faef4 SignalHandler(int) + 452
...
```

If you remove the `precondition`, then the results go to `stdout`:

```
$ cat tryit 
#! /usr/bin/env swift

println ("foo")
$ ./tryit 2> /tmp/error 1> /tmp/noterror
$ cat /tmp/noterror 
foo
$ cat /tmp/error
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've not been able to find references to `fatal error` and how it behaves in Apple's Swift book or in the developer docs, but I did find this reference at http://swiftdoc.org/func/fatalError/ which says that the `fatalError()` function "Unconditionally print a message and stop execution." If that's the case, perhaps it truly can't be caught in any sense, and I'm left with a remote crash report to get ahold of.